# How to make a (2-D array, 2-D array) in the Client Class

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am constructing the client class below, and I am just wondering if Airplane is equal to or ='s (2-D Array, 2-D Array), how do I but in a second array into the statment Airplane steveo = new Airplane(2-D Array, 2-D Array) below.

```
public class AirplaneClient
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Airplane steveo = new Airplane({"o ", "o ", "o ","o "}
                                        {"o ", "o ", "o ","o "}
                                        {"o ", "o ", "o ","o "}
                                        {"o ", "o ", "o ","o "}
                                        {"o ", "o ", "o ","o "}
                                                               );
    }
}
```

If you still confused on what my question is asking exact I am basically trying to do this code below:

```
public class AirplaneClient
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Airplane steveo = new Airplane(2-D Array, 2-D Array);
    }
}
```

I have an idea of what the syntax for this might be:

```
public class AirplaneClient
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Airplane steveo = new Airplane({"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},

                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
                                       {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "});
    }
}
```

However, I am not positive about this. Please help!

PS:

If this is helpful as well, here are the constructors for Airplane:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Airplane
{
    private String[][] first;
    private String[][] economy;
    public Airplane()
    {
        first = new String[5][4];
        economy = new String[30][6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            {
                first[i][j] = "o ";
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                economy[i][j] = "o ";
            }
        }
    }

    public Airplane(String[][] first1, String[][] economy1)
    {
        first = first1;
        economy = economy1;
    }
```

Comment: can you please add the Airplane constructor header codes?

Comment: @hasan83 yes I can

Comment: For starters - you have a ```{``` extra at the beginning, without a matching closing braces: ```new Airplane({{"o ```

Comment: Your constructor inputs are not a 2D Array.

Comment: @IvanPavičić Okay I will fix that

Comment: @MouadELFakir Sorry, typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your constructor inputs first to :

```
public Airplane(String[][] first1, String[][] economy1) {
        first = first1;
        economy = economy1;
}
```

Then call it like:

```java
Airplane steveo = new Airplane(
                new String[][] { 
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "} 
                }
                , 
                new String[][] { 
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "} 
                });
```

Comment: Are you sure the errors is from this snippet of code? because it's working fine for me, check it here : http://ideone.com/p45jID

Comment: Sorry. no I typed one little thing in wrong it was an extra bracket. This works perfectly. I will vote this as thhe best answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be to make a new Array if that type with dimensions [a][b][c][d], fill it, and then pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: that's not a bad idea and if no better answer come up I will do that. However, I would like to see if anyone can figure out an answer that is specific to the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String[][] first;
public void setFirst(String[][] first){this.first = first;}
private String[][] economy;
public void setEconomy(String[][] eco){this.economy=eco};

//outside class
String[][] one = new String[][] {
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
            };
String[][] two = new String[][] {
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "},
                    {"o ", "o ", "o ", "o "}
            };
setFirst(one);
setEconomy(two);
```

then